# deployment of Playframework to EC2 not able to init the Global object

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am new to Playframework- Trying to build a CI environment for the Play project.
I tried following the same.

- I have jenkins that does dist and upload the artifact.zip to EC2 server.
- I installed play on my EC2 under /usr/local/
- Then I copied artifact.zip to another folder on EC2
- run the artifact/bin/arc--Startup file ./arc
  And I got the below exception- what is that I am missing?

Oops, cannot start the server. @733ila33k: Cannot init the Global object
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:55)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:49)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:48)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$lzycompute(Application.scala:399)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:399) Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: rb/common/Global : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Comment: The actually error in that message is: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: rb/common/Global : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` Try looking that up.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have built the code with Java8 and deploying it to EC2 where Java7 in installed. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Yes I think that's almost certainly the problem. Either build it with Java 7 or upgrade your server to Java 8.

Comment: trying the same- I will keep posted. Thanks again !!

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
### The error may exist in config/mybatis/mapper/common/MSubsidiaryM01.xml
### The error may involve MSubsidiary.MSubsidiary#selectAll
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection